# Curl unable to get local issuer certificate on CLI

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

Am using curl on cli and it gives me the error `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)` whenever i test it with e.g. `openssl s_client -connect storage.googleapis.com:443`. Now I know there are other questions like this but none have helped me, google also has not been very helpful, solutions include running

- `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`
- `sudo update-ca-certificates`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

I have even reinstalled ca-certificates `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates` which gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 145 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20190110ubuntu1.1 [145 kB]
Fetched 145 kB in 0s (2,296 kB/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xauth' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'kbd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 200133 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20190110ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20190110ubuntu1.1) over (20190110ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20190110ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping ca-certificates.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
rehash: warning: skipping duplicate certificate in cert.pem
2 added, 2 removed; done.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping ca-certificates.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
rehash: warning: skipping duplicate certificate in cert.pem
2 added, 2 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Replacing debian:ca-certificates.pem
Replacing debian:cert.pem
Removing debian:cert.pem
Removing debian:ca-certificates.pem
done.
done.
```

I have also cleared the folder `/etc/ssl/certs/` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` but none of these have helped in any way, I have already spent a day debugging this and its driving me crazy.

Also some of the solutions I have found refer to fixing it using `php_ini` which does not work for me since am running it in CLI.

A solution to this would be highly appreciated.

`uname -a` produces:
`Linux hamisi-pc 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: If the server is improperly setup in the first place updating local certificates will not help. Is this a problem with a specific URL or with every site you try (i.e. also something like google.com)? Is this problem specific to curl or do have other client (like browsers) the same problem?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i can pretty much say its a problem with either curl or openssl, not sure since am not a linux guru because i have tried with multiple urls and am getting the same results, when i try the same on another PC (mac in this case) its running ok

Comment: Is this machine behind some corporate firewall or behind some other system which does SSL interception (for example virtual machine running as VM inside windows where an AV is installed)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no, the OS is running on hardware

Comment: Please check the output of `openssl s_client` or `curl -k` regarding the certificate which gets received. Is this really the same certificate you see from the other machines, i.e. subject, issuer etc are the same?

Comment: also i have messed with my openssl before, could that be the case?? because i remember a time it used to work, now its not anymore @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Sure, messing with the openssl setup might affect the way openssl works. But how to recover from a messed up setup depends on how it was messed up exactly - which is unknown here.

Comment: basically i had removed the version that came with Ubuntu and rebuilt it manually from the openssl repo, then removed that one and reinstalled from Ubuntu package manager (apt)

Comment: `openssl s_client` produces `140209804019008:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140209804019008:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140209804019008:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140209804019008:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219482/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-lulliezy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several debugging it turns out that

- to solve some [unspecific] problems it was tried to install another version of openssl from source
- this version was installed to `/usr/local/`, as is the default
- the version was not (fully) removed, i.e. at least  libcrypto and libssl remained in `/usr/local/lib`
- due to the default library path the libraries in `/usr/local/lib` were loaded instead of the ones in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
- since the default search path for the certificates was hard-coded in these libraries to `/usr/local/ssl/certs/` it failed to look for the certificates in the system CA store `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/`

After removing the files inside `/usr/local` it now loaded the right versions of the libraries which looked in the right path for the certificates and everything started to work again.